# How can I avoid repeating host IP address in hosts.yaml?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I like to give my hosts nicknames (e.g. `pi-master`) but also specify their IP. How do I avoid repeating the host IP in multiple places if I want to list the same host as part of two groups? In the example above I want the `pi-master` host to be part of both the `master` and `nfs` groups.

```yaml
---
master:
  hosts:
    pi-master:
      ansible_host: 192.168.1.100

node:
  hosts:
    pi-worker1:
      ansible_host: 192.168.1.101
    pi-worker2:
      ansible_host: 192.168.1.102

nfs:
  hosts:
    pi-master:
      ansible_host: 192.168.1.100
    pi-worker1:
      ansible_host: 192.168.1.101
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple: you don't need to ! I would even go further: you should not repeat since only a single value will be retained in the end.

A host is a host. Wherever you define it and as many references you write, it will always be unique and part of the [`all` default top group](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#default-groups). The resulting vars for that specific host are a combination of the vars defined anywhere. For how conflicts are resolved see [how variables are merged](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#how-we-merge) and [ansible precedence rules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable)

In the following example, I referenced the same host 3 times, adding a new variable at every location and overriding one.

**testinv.yml**

```yaml
---
group_a:
  hosts:
    my_host:
      ansible_host: 10.10.10.1

group_b:
  hosts:
    my_host:
      ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3

group_c:
  hosts:
    my_host:
      ansible_host: custom.host.com
      ansible_user: test_user
```

Below is the result of the command `ansible-inventory -i  testinv.yml --list`. As you can see, all three vars are affected to my host whatever the context in which I will use it, **and the latest override value will be used in all cases**

```json
{
    "_meta": {
        "hostvars": {
            "my_host": {
                "ansible_host": "custom.host.com",
                "ansible_python_interpreter": "/usr/bin/python3",
                "ansible_user": "test_user"
            }
        }
    },
    "all": {
        "children": [
            "group_a",
            "group_b",
            "group_c",
            "ungrouped"
        ]
    },
    "group_a": {
        "hosts": [
            "my_host"
        ]
    },
    "group_b": {
        "hosts": [
            "my_host"
        ]
    },
    "group_c": {
        "hosts": [
            "my_host"
        ]
    }
}
```

I suggest you avoid such declarations which are really error prone. Either define all the vars for your host in the top `all` group or (best solution IMHO) use a [`host_vars/<your_host>.yaml file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#organizing-host-and-group-variables)

If you really want to keep all this in a single file, in your context this could give:

```yaml
---
all:
  hosts:
    pi-master:
      ansible_host: 192.168.1.100
    pi-worker1:
      ansible_host: 192.168.0.101
    pi-worker2:
      ansible_host: 192.168.1.102
  
master:
  hosts:
    pi-master:

node:
  hosts:
    pi-worker1:
    pi-worker2:

nfs:
  hosts:
    pi-master:
    pi-worker1:
```

(You could also decide to declare the vars in the first host reference in the order it appears in the file. Declaring the `all` default group just "forces" you write those references at the top of the file.)

Answer (score -1):

you use "children" as stated by [the documents](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html).

Although it's very "ugly", in your example you can achieve this by:

```
---
host-pi-master:
  hosts:
    pi-master:
      ansible_host: 192.168.1.100

host-pi-worker1:
  hosts:
    pi-worker1:
      ansible_host: 192.168.1.101

host-pi-worker2:
  hosts:
    pi-worker2:
      ansible_host: 192.168.1.102

master:
  children:
    host-pi-master:

node:
  children:
    host-pi-worker1:
    host-pi-worker2:

nfs:
  children:
    host-pi-master:
    host-pi-worker1:
```

Comment: What is the purpose of creating supplementary groups for that ?

Comment: @Zeitounator - I don't see much difference than what you did. yours is just nicer since you aggregate everything under "all"

Comment: Mine does not have three groups such are faking a second alias to a single machine and are actually useless.